# Finding the largest factorial that is less than the number entered

Tags: java, numbers, factorial

Essentially what I want my code to do is compare the factorial result against the number that is inputted, to find the largest factorial less than the number inputted. For some reason, it's not printing anything.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     int numinput = 150; //number than we are trying to find the largest factorial less than
     int num = 1; //number than we are solving a factorial for, to test against numinput
     int factorial = 1; //actual result of the factorial
     while (factorial < numinput) //finds the factorial of num
       for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
         factorial *= i;
       }
     num++;
     if (factorial > numinput) {
        num--;
        System.out.println("The largest factorial less than " + numinput + "is !" + factorial);
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `while` loop doesn't have curly braces, so the only thing in the loop's body is the `for` loop. `num` starts at `1`, and nothing inside the loop ever increases it, so it would loop forever.

You don't need a nested loop, though - a single loop that calculates the factorial as you go should suffice:

```
int numinput = 150; //number than we are trying to find the largest factorial less than
int num = 1;
int factorial = 1;

while (factorial < numinput) {
    num++;
    factorial *= num;
}

// We overshot to terminate the loop, go back one number
factorial /= num;
num--;

System.out.println
    ("The largest factorial less than " + numinput + " is " + num + "!, or " + factorial);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your code cannot get out of this while loop-

```
while (factorial < numinput) //finds the factorial of num
       for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
         factorial *= i;
       }
```

Since you haven't used parentheses in your while loop, it has just got the for loop, and since the value of `num` never increases, it keeps on multiplying `factorial` by 1 forever. I think you wanted to do this -

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     int numinput = 150; //number than we are trying to find the largest factorial less than
     int num = 1; //number than we are solivng a factorial for, to test agaisnt numinput
     int factorial = 1; //actual result of the factorial
     while (factorial < numinput) {
        for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            factorial *= i;
        }
        num++;
        if (factorial > numinput) {
            num--;
            System.out.println("The largest factorial less than " + numinput + "is !" + factorial);
        }
     }
  }
}
```

But I checked the output of your code for 150, and it is not correct. I am providing my code below -

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     int numinput = 150; //number than we are trying to find the largest factorial less than
     int num = 1; //number than we are solivng a factorial for, to test agaisnt numinput
     int factorial = 1; //actual result of the factorial
     while (factorial <= numinput) {    // continue multiplying even if equal
        factorial = 1;
        for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            factorial *= i;
        }
        num++;
     }
    // now the factorial is surely greater than numinput, and it is the factorial of
    // current value of num - 1, we can remove the conditional
    // and reduce the factorial by num -1 since multiplying by num - 1 has
    // made it bigger than numinput
    factorial /= (num - 1);
    System.out.println("The largest factorial less than " + numinput + "is !" + factorial);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am supposing that you are saying the least integer factorial that is less than the entered factorial. So, the code should look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int input = 150; // example 
    for (int i = 1; i <= input - 1; i++) {
    int sum = (input - 1) * 1;
    }

    System.out.println(input);
}
```